# While selecting the parameter1 i need to set para2,para3 based on this values

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a ssrs reprot and added 3 parameters for the report. I am filling values to parameter through dataset. While selecting the parameter1 i need to set para2,para3 based on this values. Cannot set  as default value because need to change whenever para1 is changing.

Is any option to do this in ssrs 2008?.

Thanks in advance 
pvn

Answer (score 0):

You can still set a default value for the 2nd and 3rd parameter. Just base it off a dataset that *uses* the first parameter.

Supposing the following:

- First parameter is `@CountryId`
- Second parameter is `@ProvinceId`
- Third parameter is `@LanguageId`

Now suppose you have this dataset for the available values for the first parameter:

```sql
SELECT CountryId, CountryName
FROM Countries
```

Then for second parameter `@ProvinceId` you set the default values based on this dataset:

```sql
SELECT ProvinceId
FROM CountryProvinces
WHERE CountryProvinces.CountryId = @CountryId
```

And for the third parameter `@LanguageId` something similar:

```sql
SELECT LanguageId
FROM CountryLanguages
WHERE CountryLanguages.CountryId = @CountryId
```

Now, whenever "para1 is changing" the second and third parameter will refresh their values accordingly.